# Maven multiple repositories in pom but "Missing artifact" with JBoss repository

Tags: maven, jboss, repository

I've added two repositories to my pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>objectify-appengine</id>
        <url>http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

but get 'Missing artifact ...' for all dependencies except jboss.(can't get dependencies from central and objectify)

Tried to add repositories to the settings.xml. But no effect. 
What wrong?

Comment: what does `mvn help:effective-pom` show in repositories?

Comment: in effective pom for additional http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. Problem was in jboss: I've changed url to http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss and have added '.Final' to verison. No problem now. Thanks.

Comment: Better start using a repository manager, cause in pom's you should avoid repository definitions.

Comment: Write your solution as an answer or close your post.

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is deprecated, update it this way :

```xml
<project >
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss Public repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Oh ! Sorry ! I didn't saw that you already manage to solve your issue. As Kayser said, post your answer, accept it when you'll be able to (in a few days, 2 days as far as I know), and we'll vote it up !